# Civi Never Remebers the last selection?

Tags: admin

CiviCRM In Joomla CMS.

Everytime I click edit on ANY part of Civi it does not remember the last settings and they have to be put in again.

example:
If i edit a contact and select the primary email address, save it, okay.
return to said contact record to add something unrelated "phone number" its forgotten which email i previously saved as primary and wont allow me to save until rechecked. This happens every time on every page requiring a selection.

It's worse in the admin pages, If i want to change display preferences i have to remember "EVERYTHING" I last selected. Everytime I access the page all the last settings are removed....

[image]

Comment: have you confirmed this is not happening on demo?

Comment: Hi Petednz, I haven't I honestly don't know how, civicrm is a monster and software is not my field. We have recently installed it on our Joomla just to trial and are working with a few developers on Upwork to assist.

Comment: I was hoping it was just a quick fix but developer says not so much, were letting him work but obviously I don't know how long or much this should cost and was hoping for some guidance on where he should look etc.

Comment: this sounds to me like an installation 'failure' but can't point you to what it might be